# Python For Loop to add row with data

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I would like to create a `for loop` that iterates throughout a list to add dummy rows to the bottom of my dataframe.  In order to make a report line up period over the period I need to ensure that all fields are represented even if each field has a zero balance:

I am new to python, and this is above my competency level with regard to simple for loops:

```
list = ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Grapes']
```

output:
The fields that I need data for are Date(this will be variable but will be the same for each dataframe), fruit (I need the name from the above [list] supplied for each line item), sector (will equal 'other') and value (will always equal 0.00)

```
Date      Team    Sector    Value
12/31/17  Orange  Other     0.00
12/31/17  Apple   Other     0.00
12/31/17  Grapes  Other     0.00
```

Comment: Your question is unclear , what you need ? can you show expected out put ?

Comment: Side note: you should not use `list` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin function `list`.

Comment: Wen, I apologize for any confusion, i am hoping to achieve the table listed above as the output.  So the dataframe's output would include a column for date(based on a variable), team(equal to element in list) sector(sector will equal 'other) and value will always equal 0.00

Comment: @RoadRunner- thank you!  again, being new to Python/programming, can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

## code

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31'),
                       'Team' : ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Grapes'],
                       'Sector': 'other',
                      'Value' : 0.00})
  print(df)
```

## out

```
        Date    Team Sector  Value
0 2017-12-31  Orange  other    0.0
1 2017-12-31   Apple  other    0.0
2 2017-12-31  Grapes  other    0.0
```

Comment: SciPy thank you so much! This is Great!  for the date column, can i utilize a variable vs hardcoding the date in pd.to_datetime()?

Comment: yes of course, but with pd.to_datetime, you have more options (e.g., extract the month, the year... from a  date in a text format